# Map N number of mono calls in spring boot web flux

Tags: spring-boot, webflux

I have a method in spring boot that makes multiple mono call that returns a type string. This method will eventually return the results of all the mono calls which are later transformed into a POJO object. Tried Mono.zip but this accepts only 8 tuples. Is there a better solution?

eg:

```java
Mono<String> mono1 = <Web client call>
Mono<String> mono2 = <Web client call>
Mono<String> mono3 = <Web client call>
Mono<String> mono4 = <Web client call>
.
.
.
.
.
.
Mono<String> monoN = <Web client call>
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a static method on `Mono` that allows you to do this with an arbitrary number of Monos:

```java
public static <R> Mono<R> zip(Function<? super Object[],? extends R> combinator, Mono<?>... monos)
```

Reference documentation: https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#zip-java.util.function.Function-reactor.core.publisher.Mono...-

In Kotlin we can use it as

```kotlin
Mono.zip({ it.size }, mono1, mono2)
```

In this case you would now have a `Mono<Int>`, but you can aggregate the objects as you see fit.

Comment: Could you please show me a practical example of the same?

Comment: I've edited my answer because I found another relevant method in `Mono`.